# REST GET recordset Response

Tags: node.js, rest

I have developed a pure node.js REST application server that connects to a MSSQL DB and uses endpoints to request employee records.

I am receiving duplicate records back when I request all employee records or when I request one employee record using a REST GET request.  The response has both a recordsets and recordset section.  Is this correct and if it is, how do I prevent duplicate records?

You help would be greatly appreciated.

db.js

```
exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {
    var conn = new sqlDb.ConnectionPool(settings.dbConfig);
    conn.connect()
        .then(function () {
            var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
            req.query(sql)
                .then(function (recordset) {
                    callback(recordset);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(null, err);
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(null, err);
        });
};
```

employee.js

```
var db = require("../core/db");
var httpMsgs = require("../core/httpMsgs");
var util = require("util");

exports.getList = function (req, resp) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE", function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        }
        else {
            httpMsgs.showJSON(req, resp, data);
        }
    });
};

exports.get = function (req, resp, empno) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER =" + empno, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        }
        else if (data.recordset >= "0") {
            (httpMsgs.showJSON(req, resp, data));
        }
        else {
            httpMsgs.show404(req, resp, err);
        }
    });

};
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var emp = require("../controllers/employees");
var settings = require("../settings");
var httpMsgs = require("./httpMsgs");

http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    switch (req.method) {
        case "GET":
            if (req.url === "/") {
                httpMsgs.showHome(req, resp);
            }
            else if (req.url === "/employees") {
                emp.getList(req, resp);
            }
            else {
                var empnoPatt = "[A-Za-z0-9_]+";
                var patt = new RegExp("/employees/" + empnoPatt);
                if (patt.test(req.url)) {
                    patt = new RegExp(empnoPatt);
                    var empno = req.url.split('/')[2];
                    emp.get(req, resp, empno);
                }
                else {
                    httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
                }
            }
            break;
        case "POST":
            if (req.url === "/employees") {
                var reqBody = "";
                req.on("data", function (data){
                    reqBody += data;
                    if (reqBody.length > 1e7) //10MB
                    {
                        httpMsgs.show413(req, resp);
                    };
                });
            }
            else {
                httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
            }
            break;
        case "PUT":
            if (req.url === "/employees") {

            }
            else {
                httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
            }
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            if (req.url === "/employees") {

            }
            else {
                httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
            }
            break;
        default:
            httpMsgs.show405(req, resp);
            break;
    }

}).listen(settings.webPort, function () {
    console.log("Server Started Listening at: " + settings.webPort);
});
```

This is the httpMsgs that returns a stringify from the JSON response

```
exports.showJSON = function (req, resp, data) {
    resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    resp.end();
};
```

This is the JSON response I get back when requesting employee record where employee_number = 100

```
{
  "recordsets": [
    [
      {
        "RECORD_KEY": "951112558721130050",
        "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER": "100",
        "FIRST_NAME": "SAMPLE CLERK",
        "LAST_NAME": null,
      }
    ]
  ],
  "recordset": [
    {
      "RECORD_KEY": "951112558721130050",
      "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER": "100",
      "FIRST_NAME": "SAMPLE CLERK",
      "LAST_NAME": null,
    }
  ],
  "output": {},
  "rowsAffected": [
    1
  ]
}
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of code missing: we have no idea what happens when you handle the request (i.e. the function calling `executeSql`, the callback...).

Comment: I have updated the question with more code.  I left out the httpMsgs.js that is used to handle http formatted message to the user.  As we as the database connection settings (settings.js)

Comment: You are passing through `data` property from the `sqldb` driver without change, hence your problem is db-driver implementation-specific. But if i'd have to guess, one recordset is the rows and recordset**s** might contain the recent queries of this process.